# How to speed up SQL like %pattern% searches?

Tags: sql-server, performance

Is there any way to speed up queries like this below ? I am looking for option which would require minimal change to application code.

```
SELECT  *
FROM my_table 
WHERE some_column like '%my string%' 
ORDER BY some_column
```

The table which causes most of the slowdown has 2,5 million records and query takes 10 seconds to execute.
Execution plan tells that 99% of the cost is index scan (NonClustered), which is understandable because of LIKE and pattern with "%" on both sides.
If there is "%" just at the end, then index seek is used and query executes in a moment.

So I am looking for something like:

- to add some kind of aditional index on the table, probably not
  possible ?
- a way to put this table and/or index into RAM sa the seek would be
  faster
- anything else ?

I can use either MS SQL 2012 or 2014, both standard edition.

**Bonus question**

Is it possible that this very same queries would execute instanteniously on DB2 database ? App was using db2 initially but was migrated over to MS SQL.

Comment: Did you try `FULL TEXT` search

Comment: Full text search will require a change to the code though to use full text predicates rather than like.

Comment: No way, it will be a full scan. It can be optimized if you remove leading percent sign:  like 'string%'. You will get this if you know how search works in trees. Engine has to search through all nodes.

Comment: If it's the only predicate, there's nothing you can do.  Indexing that column is still an index scan, no help there.  If you can remove the leading or trailing '%', then there are tricks.  If it's not the only predicate, then focus on reducing their impact as much as possible to improve the total time.

Comment: I can't remove leading or trailing '%', application breaks in various ways if I do. So is there any option to have this in RAM so the scan would be faster ?

Comment: hey @Primoz you might can use your relational knowledge of database, ie might be you can relate some_column  to another column, might be like
where ome_column like '%my string% and someothercolumn =somevalue.
OR might required some database level changes 
OR full text search 
OR NO SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the column `collation` to some binary form:

in query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM my_table 
WHERE some_column COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN like '%my string%' 
ORDER BY some_column
```

or change it in the table design permanently if you can.

Caveat: it's cAsE sEnSiTiVe.

Edit: you can get around case sensitivity by converting both the column and the search string to upper case for example:

```
SELECT  *
FROM my_table 
WHERE UPPER(some_column) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN like '%MY STRING%' 
ORDER BY some_column
```

Edit 2: backup the database before doing any perpanent collation changes, I'm not sure how exactly it compares but I think in query it should be ok.

[Explation article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31238.t-sql-improve-the-performance-for-like-wildcard-by-changing-the-collation.aspx#Binary_Collation).

Answer (score 0):

There may not be an answer, but there is a reason. When you use a search string with a leading wildcard, such as '%string', you're forcing the optimizer to do a table scan.

You might want to revisit some of the suggestions in this thread.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure this solution is an option for you as it stores more data in database. it also may increase the time for update/insert, but its an idea anyway. Too long to put in to comment, so don't blame me!

- Add a persisted computed column for the some_column with this formula: REVERSE(some_column) to store reverse of the string
- Add index on that column
- In your query use `some_column like 'my string%' or rev_some_column like REVERSE('%my string')`. You'd better to replace REVERSE('%my string') with a variable initiated before query.

I think in this case, both likes will use index.

Comment: It seems interesting idea, but unfortunately would require code change.

Comment: It's also irrelevant to the question, which has both a leading and trailing wildcard.

Comment: @MartinSmith, did you see my where clause? I have considered both case, if not please explan so I can understand.

Comment: The op is asking how to speed up searches with both a leading and trailing wildcard. Your index doesn't help. The reverse index would only help looking for patterns like `%pattern` where the substring is guaranteed to occur at the end of the string, not `%pattern%` where it can occur anywhere.

Comment: You are right! look like there is no answer for the question